# Unreliable Android Jetpack benchmarking library measurement results?

Tags: android, profiling, benchmarking, android-jetpack, firebase-test-lab

I've used [Android Jetpack benchmarking framework](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/benchmark) on different **non-rooted** devices for some trivial calculations:

```
    @Test
    fun measurePureCalculation() {
        benchmarkRule.measureRepeated {
            val value = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5
            println(value)
        }
    }
```

If i run it locally for 10 times on exactly the same device i can see different results:

```
benchmark:        13,831 ns Benchmark.measurePureCalculation
benchmark:        13,688 ns Benchmark.measurePureCalculation
benchmark:        13,773 ns Benchmark.measurePureCalculation
benchmark:        13,933 ns Benchmark.measurePureCalculation
benchmark:        13,823 ns Benchmark.measurePureCalculation
benchmark:        13,581 ns Benchmark.measurePureCalculation
benchmark:        13,930 ns Benchmark.measurePureCalculation
benchmark:        14,008 ns Benchmark.measurePureCalculation
benchmark:        13,727 ns Benchmark.measurePureCalculation
benchmark:        13,995 ns Benchmark.measurePureCalculation
```

In this measurements set above it gives measurement error ((max - min) / max) = ((14008 - 13581 / 14008) = ~3%.

In general it seems it gives very unstable results which can be different by 8-13% depending on code that is measured (a piece from generated benchmark JSON files - tested on test farm with real device):

```
"median": 7473,
...
"median": 7222,
...
"median": 8065,
...
"median": 7409,
...
"median": 6926,
```

Here (above) the measurement inaccuracy is (8065 - 6926)/8065 = ~14%.

It makes me think the measurements results are not reliable enough as it does not help to understand if the code is changed for a better or worse or it's just a measurement inaccuracy.

I do understand i did not lock CPU frequency due to lack of permissions on non-rooted device, but i expect it to work (by other means as mentioned in framework [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZffMCJdA5Qc)).

We've tried with a couple of devs on different devices (obviously comparing the results for the same models) and even a test farm with real devices (eg. TestObject). All the settings were set by default (release build, default benchmarking strategy). Version used is:

> classpath "androidx.benchmark:benchmark-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"

Do you have the same experience? What is another [possible] reason except not locked CPU frequency? Any suggestion on what can be checked/investigated further? What are the options in general to understand if we improve the code over releases? Can using of Firebase Test Lab help here?

Update:

As Chris pointed it's indeed compile-time optimized into just value `120` (totally forgot about it, reverse engineered from bytecode[image]), so it's unclear what is essentially measured:

Answer (score 1):

Library developer here, thanks for the detailed question -

First, have you tried something that's simpler to measure this baseline stability? Generally stability will be much higher if your work is consistent, and especially if it's single threaded. I expect (but haven't checked) that `println()` may be unstable in performance due to buffering underneath, which may result in inconsistent amounts of work from loop to loop. You can also try to work around this by doing `measureRepeated { repeat(100) {...} }`, but no guarantees that would work.

If you're looking for a tiny chunk of CPU work as a baseline for optimal stability measurements, I'd suggest something like [this](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:benchmark/common/src/main/java/androidx/benchmark/ThrottleDetector.kt;l=47;drc=18266f9efb44e8e63a45e055ffd471dd11544c02). That's a small bit of matrix math that the Benchmark library measures internally to detect thermal throttling. Since it's a call into platform code, it's guaranteed not to be optimized out (unlike the multiplication you're doing, which will be folded down to `println(120)` at compile time).

Additionally, try looking at `min` as well as `median`, to see if that gives you more stability. In general, interference makes things slower, not faster, since by the time that warmup is over, your clocks are likely ramped up as high as they'll go.

The higher stability, the smaller a regression you can catch, and we see a wide range of stability in our CI, depending on workload. We're constantly working both on the library and benchmarks themselves to get better stability. Even low stability benchmarks though can be useful for finding big surprise regressions.

Admittedly, in our own benchmark usage within Jetpack, all of our benchmarks run on clock-locked rooted devices. You can however see all the results and stability for yourself, for example some [trivial synchronization benchmarks](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:benchmark/benchmark/src/androidTest/java/androidx/benchmark/benchmark/SynchronizedBenchmark.kt;drc=22c33928f8aa7151e4dd5cab8efdbf1a7061861d) have results [here](https://androidx-perf.skia.org/e/?queries=sdk_release_name%3DAPI_28_P%26sub_result%3Dtime_nanos_min%26test%3Dandroidx.benchmark.benchmark.SynchronizedBenchmark_atomicIncrementBenchmark%26test%3Dandroidx.benchmark.benchmark.SynchronizedBenchmark_synchronizedIncrementBenchmark), which have about a 3% difference from min to max today, ignoring a couple outliers:

[image: Results from Jetpack CI, showing ~3% difference between max and min]

In practice, I've found that the content of the benchmark matters a lot more for stability than locking clocks, though I'd really like for us to test on non-rooted eventually.

Note that we also gave a [followup presentation at Droidcon TO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yszRpGp3ijI), about how to use this data in CI, and deal with periodic instability.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation.Actually we started from measuring some much more complicated piece of the code, found it not enough accurate and eventually tried the snippet i've posted just to check.I've been thinking about "release" optimization and `println` buffering but it felt like a natural use case, so i expected to have more-or-less reliable results (3% sounds acceptable, but 14%). I guess it was just unclear what accuracy can be expected as normal. After the announcement on IO19 i was really impressed how hard it is in fact so expected thermal throttling is somehow solved.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the possible directions, going to test on rooted device and see what happens